# Save Dialog Message and Empty path names

Tags: c#

I am currently working `Open file` and `write file` functions in C#. I am going through two problems: When the user is in the process of saving a file, if he/she exits the save dialog and nothing is saved I get an error(look at picture below for description). How can my program avoid this and not crash? and Is there away to display a message after the file has been saved?

[image]

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SaveFileDialog saveReport = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveReport.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";
                saveReport.ShowDialog();

                StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(saveReport.FileName);
                writeFile.Write(textBox1.Text);
                writeFile.Close();

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var saveReport = new SaveFileDialog();
saveReport.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";
var result = saveReport.ShowDialog();

if(result == DialogResult.Cancel || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(saveReport.FileName))
    return;

using(var writer = new StreamWriter(saveReport.FileName))
{
    writer.Write(textBox1.Text);
    writer.Close();
}

MessageBox.ShowDialog("File Saved!");
```

In principle the FileName will never be `null` or whitespace -- the dialog prevents it unless you cancel, but I include it for clarity.

Comment: Thank you, but i am getting this error: `'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox' does not contain a definition for 'ShowDialog'`

Answer (score 1):

If the user clicks Cancel, `ShowDialog()` will return `DialogResult.Cancel`.

You can check for this in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the return value of your [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) call to determine what the user selected.

The code below saves only if the user selected OK in the dialog:

```
SaveFileDialog saveReport = new SaveFileDialog();
saveReport.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";
if (saveReport.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(saveReport.FileName);
    writeFile.Write(textBox1.Text);
    writeFile.Close();
}
```

The problem with your original code was that you were attempting to save even if the user did not specify a file name through the dialog.